# OpenVPN & iptables - allow traffic to certain specific hosts on server side

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, vpn

I setup an OpenVPN server on a Raspberry Pi and configured it according to the [HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).
I want to expose certain hosts from the server-subnet (192.168.123.0/24) the clients.

I used

`push route 192.168.123.0 255.255.255.0`

in the server.conf file. Also I setup `iptables` the following way:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#allow ssh and vpn on pi - working fine
...
```

According to [OpenVPN - access policies](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#policy) this shoud allow traffich forwarding to either a specific host or the entire subnet (lines extracted from the HOWTO - these addresses are not my actual address ranges):

```
# Employee rule
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.66.4.4 -j ACCEPT

# Sysadmin rule
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.1.0/24 -d 10.66.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Contractor rule
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.2.0/24 -d 10.66.4.12 -j ACCEPT
```

Neither of this helps. However if I set

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

and nothing else, I can see all of the hosts, which I do not want. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in layer 8 all along!

I forgot to allow the traffic passing back through my tunneling device.

The solution is

```
#Set default policy of chain 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#allow traffic to route from VPN subnet to specific host in subnet
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s {VPN subnet} -d {host in server subnet} -j ACCEPT
#allow traffic from host in server subnet back to VPN subnet
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -s {host in server subnet} -d {VPN subnet}
```

I was inspired by this post here:

https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=20369